# How to append a before_filter in gem after all other controller before_filters in a Rails3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

There's a gem, which **appends** a `before_filter` to a Rails app:

```
class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
  initializer "..." do
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
      ActionController::Base.send(:include, Filter)

...

module Filter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    append_before_filter :set_locale
  end

  def set_locale
     ....
```

And here's some controller in the app:

```
class DesktopsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_language_in_session
```

Now the problem with this is that the `before_filter` from the gem is being put in the filter chain before the `before_filter` from the DesktopsController:

```
DesktopsController._process_action_callbacks.select { |c| c.kind == :before }.collect { |filter| filter.filter }
=> [
    [0] :set_locale,
    [1] :set_language_in_session
]
```

How can I make the `before_filter` from the gem (**set_locale**) be put **after** all other filters? The secret probably lies in this line:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
```

But I've tried different libraries without any luck...

Btw. Here's the [full code](https://github.com/Exvo/locale_detector) of the gem. Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapting the gem will never work. The gem is initialised as one of the first things in the rails process, so before any actual controller is ever launched. So this means, that whatever you do, most likely the filter from the gem will still remain the first gem.

So the only solutions I see are:

- using `prepend_before_filter` in your own controllers for those actions that need to come before the `set_locale`.
- if you need explicit control, use the `skip_before_filter` and explicit `before_filter`.

In a rails 2 application, we devised a hack to make sure that some filter was run as last filter, by overriding the `perform_action_without_filters` (see [Is there a way to force a before_filter to always execute last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118445/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-before-filter-to-always-execute-last)) but we removed that when upgrading to rails 3.

Comment: While gem can be initialized/loaded as first thing in the bootup process, there is this: `ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do` which makes the actual initialization of the gem's core delayed. That's why I thought it might be possible to wait for all controllers to load.

Comment: True, but all controllers depend on `ActionController`, so imho it will come before all other controllers.

Comment: Yes, you are right :) That's the main reason for this SO question :)

Comment: Since the answer to this question is "it's not possible" I guess I'll mark your answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on nickgrim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447381/how-to-append-a-before-filter-in-gem-after-all-other-controller-before-filters-in/7469458#7469458), which I also found quite clever. The block passed to `included` gets class evaled (`class_eval`) when the module is included. You can make `set_locale_filter` a class method by defining it in the `included` block (among other ways).

```
module Filter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    append_before_filter :set_locale_filter

    def self.set_locale_filter
      append_before_filter :set_locale
    end
  end

  def set_locale
    # 
  end
end
```

Somebody, please correct me if I'm mistaken. It's late here :)

Comment: Good try! Although this unfortunately still fails :/ with this message: `undefined local variable or method `set_locale_filter' for #<DesktopsController:0xb008dbc>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class DesktopsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :set_locale
  before_filter      :set_language_in_session
  before_filter      :set_locale
end
```

**Reference**

[`skip_before_filter` doc](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000323)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not a solution. The reason it's appending a `before_filter` in the gem is that it has to run in more than 1 controller (imagine 20). I could just as well remove the `before_filter` addition from the gem and add `before_filter :set_locale` in every controller that needs it. But this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but you might check out prepend_before_filter, which claims to bump the provided filter to the top of the list (and ultimately before :set_locale).

```
class DesktopsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter      :set_language_in_session
end
```

Docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/prepend_before_filter

Another thing to try is using an around_filter for :set_language_in_session (even though you're not doing anything after the action). Around filters happen before before_filters, so it could be a good way to force it to happen first.

Comment: `prepend_before_filter` is not a solution. I want to modify the gem, not every controller in every app that uses this gem. Also `around_filters` are not really a solution as they execute twice for each action -- this is definitely not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The gem itself is on Github so you're able to fork it and make the code changes, then have your code pull **your** version of the gem instead. Is this an option? If so, you could just comment out the `before_filer` in the gem and call it yourself in your `ApplicationController`:

```ruby
module Filter
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # append_before_filter :set_locale
  end

  def set_locale
    ....
```

Now just call it yourself after all of your other filters:

```ruby
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :do_this, :do_that, :set_locale
  ...
end
```

Whatta ya think?

Comment: It's my gem so I don't need to fork it, I can just change it. Anyway, your proposal is not really a solution but just a workaround and as such not really useful as I would need to declare this before_filter for all controllers in all apps, which use this gem.

Comment: If you put it in `ApplicationController` then you wouldn't need to put it into each individual one. And for those controllers that you *don't* want to have the behavior you can add a `skip_before_filter :set_locale`

Comment: Actually this is more or less what I'm doing currently. I'm just executing the `set_locale` for the 2nd time in this critical place. It's still a workaround/hack, though.

Answer (score -1):

Not tried this at all, but: could you have the gem's `before_filter` run `append_before_filter`? Something like:

```
module Filter
  ...

  included do
    append_before_filter :append_set_locale_filter
  end

  def append_set_locale_filter
    append_before_filter :set_locale
  end

  def set_locale
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: This seems like a clever hack, unfortunately I cannot make it work. `append_before_filter` is a class method, so I've tried calling `self.append_before_filter` or `class << self; append_before_filter :set_locale; end` but without any luck.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I'd probably write a piece of middleware that does your operation, because then you don't have to worry about the order the filters happen.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_on_rack.html

Comment: Uhm, I'm not sure it would solve anything. It's just a `before_filter`s ordering in Rails, which is a problem. Seems Rails does not provide a way to achieve what I want.